# Banshee is unable to determine audio cd metadata

Tags: 11.04, banshee, metadata, cd-ripping

I tried to add a audio cd to my music pool.

When I enable the "Audio CD Support" extension the following output where posted via debug-mode. Now when I take a look to the cd, I realised that banshee was not able to fetch the metadata.

```
[1 Debug 19:05:59.889] Mapping audio CD (/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0a.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sr0)
[1 Debug 19:05:59.890] Extension service started (AudioCdService, 0,054336)
[6 Info  19:05:59.892] Querying MusicBrainz for Disc Release (uuz7WMxmyUfmRfJA4V7uLJ1zBJ8-)
[6 Warn  19:06:00.842] Caught an exception - System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object (in `Banshee.AudioCd')
  at Banshee.AudioCd.AudioCdDiscModel.LoadDiscMetadata (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[6 Info  19:06:00.842] Query finished (success: False, 0,94958 seconds)
```

Banshee reports:

> (-) Could not fetch track information

Due to the fact that `abcde` was able to fetch the metadata and the audio cd is "Adele 21" (so well known) i thought that there has to be a fault on my or banshee's side.

I found no extension which seems to be important for that. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like a bug in Banshee MusicBrainz support. Did you check the bug tracker?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Banshee 2.2, both of these issues have been fixed. Ubuntu 11.10 comes with this version of Banshee installed by default.

There are a couple reasons that this could happen:

1. MusicBrainz recently changed the way that third party applications can request metadata, and [this change caused problems with Banshee](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649401).
2. Until recently, if a MusicBrainz DiscID matches multiple albums, [Banshee failed to retrieve the metadata](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=587264).  The recent changes to MusicBrainz make this problem more common.

Given the NullReferenceException warning in your log, which looks pretty similar to [a log posted in the MusicBrainz forums](http://forums.musicbrainz.org/viewtopic.php?pid=10402#p10402), it seems likely that you are running into issue #2.

Answer (score 3):

In Banshee, this has been fixed now, but only after version 2.1.0. If you really care to look into the details, the change was committed on [2011-05-28](http://git.gnome.org/browse/banshee/commit/?id=ee467bdcf9fe97ed161deef3c5108d2bf5f54db5) but the 2.1.0 branch was created on [2011-05-12](http://git.gnome.org/browse/banshee/tag/?id=2.1.0).

If you are really itching to get this working again, here are the steps you have to follow: (Warning, this is the daily repo so you will get lots of update notifications and there is a higher risk of bug introduction.)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:banshee-team/banshee-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```