# Banshee not able to get track information?

Tags: 11.04, banshee

Everytime I try to copy a CD to Banshee I get an "unable to fetch track information" message? (While connected to internet)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/43905/2079

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using Sound Juicer (aka Audio CD Extractor, available in the software centre)? I often get the 'unable to fetch track info' error message in Banshee, and most of the time have no problem with Sound Juicer. It seems that when there is a conflict (there are two possible titles for the given cd), Banshee throws this message. Sound Juicer on the other hand has a dialog asking which is the 'correct' title. After using Sound Juicer, do a rescan in Banshee.

Answer (score 0):

This has always been the case with Banshee, and given that it is apparently frozen in development, this is not going to change.

I always used Asunder to rip CDs, but since freedb/CDDB has been shut down, Asunder can no longer find the album data.

The best I can currently recommend is to use Sound Juicer to rip the CD, rename the files in Banshee (unless you are happy with Sound Juicer's very limited file naming options (e.g. 'number. title' is not an option)), and then transcode the files to your desired quality using Sound Converter (unless you are happy with the lack of file quality options available in Sound Juicer).

Unfortunately, no one in 'Linux' has the ability to come up with an application that can do all these things at once, even though all this could be done in iTunes7, 15 years ago!

Answer (score 0):

Update!

Use Asunder.

Asunder can once again fetch track information:

In Asunder 'preferences > advanced', change 'CDDB server' address to either 'freedb.gnudb.org' or 'gnudb.gnudb.org'. The only caveat is that the information might not be the most up to date.

Use Asunder if you want more file type & album & file naming options & control over output file quality (e.g. bitrate/compression level). All of the metadata is compatible with Banshee, can be fully edited using Banshee, AND will be FULLY updated in terms of ACTUAL folder & file names, the only exception being that edited WAV files may show 'unknown artist' or 'unknown album' in a personal/portable music player.

In my experience, no other (Linux) media player or tag editor has this capacity, which is what makes Banshee perfect for creating compilation albums.

Asunder alongside Banshee is the best combination I have ever found.